# .htaccess RewriteRule Not Working on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

A client asked me to built them a site with WordPress. I'm not very good at WordPress so the solution may already be on here, but I've read about a dozen SO questions and haven't figured out an answer yet so I'd thought I'd post my own.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^podcast/([^/]+)$ /podcast?slug=$1 [QSA,L] #I added this

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

With my file like this, it redirects me to my 404 page. Even though the URL is correct (`/podcast/word`) the browser console says it's a 404.

I then assumed if I added an "R=301" flag, it would work around that issue. But if I do this:

```
RewriteRule ^podcast/([^/]+)$ /podcast?slug=$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

Then my browser just takes me to `/podcast?slug=word`.

I'm not sure if this is caused by my .htaccess or if it's caused by the WordPress 404 file. On the off chance anybody wants to see it, my 404.php file is:

```
<?php get_header();  ?>

<section class="white">
    <div class="wrapper internal">
       <!--generic error message-->
    </div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

My .htaccess file worked fine when using Wolf CMS, but not with WordPress. Being as I'm still learning WordPress, any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm using the slug to reference a podcast from an RSS feed. I'm looking to turn `http://example.com/podcast/?slug=example-podcast` into `http://example.com/podcast/example-podcast`, but whenever I do that I get a 404.

Comment: Let Wordpress do the work. Log into the admin page. Select Settings then permalinks. Select which option that you want to use or create you own.

Comment: @jeff I don't think I explained myself properly. I have added some additional information to the question. The slug is not part of the actual site. I'm using it to reference an external resource.

Comment: What does your wordpress set up look like? Is the the admin dir in a subdirectory but the site in the main dir (so site would be in / but all the wp files are in, say, /wordpress)? Or is everything in the same folder?

Comment: Also, you can test your regexes here: https://regex101.com/ - can you make sure they work properly? (just make sure that when you test in there, you escape the / character - actually I don't know if you have to escape the / in [^/] part for htaccess).

Comment: Use WP rewrite API instead of .htaccess for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to replace your .htaccess with this code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: How would this help? This is the default .htaccess file.

Comment: Exactly do not undo this default .htaccess file unless you have a different directory for your wordpress files.

Comment: Two years later I know better. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 0):

Example: if I had my wordpress inside a folder named 'a' as a sub directory then I will edit my .htaccess like this

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c="">
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /a/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /a/index.php [L]
</ifmodule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Then make sure you also follow the step from @jeff to Select Settings then set your permalinks. I think that would do.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can set permalink to Post Name. This will fix if your url are define by a post name instead of php type of url.